# Traefik for both intranet and internet

Tags: traefik

I run a home server with a couple of dockerized services and traefik as a reverse proxy. Some of these services (e.g. a blog) should be available to the outside while others (e.g. my file server) should not. However I would like to be able to access both of them them with `blog.mydomain.com` and `files.mydomain.com`, respectively (where the latter of course should only be reachable from within the network).

Is this possible with traefik?

Comment: Hi, it is theorically possible, with traefik 2.0- beta, and it's ipwhitelist middlewares, tough I never achieved to make use of it, and didn't put much effort into it too.
So  I'll be glad to know if you achieve to :)